# Eclipse SVN : Connect to other pc repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

I already created a repository via Eclipse SVN in my local folder. I can check-in/check-out normally using this address

```
file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/Repository/first_repository
```

Now, I'm trying to connect that repository from other pc in a local area network using this address

```
http://<IP_address>/Users/MyUser/Documents/Repository/first_repository
```

But it throw me an error

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
svn: Unable to connect to repository at URL 'http://<path>'
svn: Error running context : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

How to fix this so that i can check-in/check-out from other pc ? I'm using windows.

Comment: You need to be running a SVN server on the other machine to make this work.

Comment: @greg-449 Oh ok thanks